# Error handling in ASP .Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling

Being a newbie to MVC, I tried to implement custom error handling in my demo application.
I tried a few steps fro this document 
[Error Handling Document](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages)
but the custom error page for error 404 is not being shown.

Here is what I have tried so far .

My web.config looks like :

[image]

And the FilterConfig.cs looks like :

[image]

And here is the custom sample error page page404.html for the initial round of testing :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Page is not there dude !!</h1>
    Sorry about this.
</body>
</html>
```

But still when a request a url which is not configured into my application, I still get the trivial page not found error page.

[image]

What am I missing ?

**Update**

I understand next I have to update the error page to be an .aspx page. But for now I just want the initial version to work.

Please find the web.config below :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/page404.html"/> <!--On all 404 pages, show page404.aspx-->
    </customErrors>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>

    <!--
        Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
        after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
        MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
        To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
        controller or action.
    -->
    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>

    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />  
  </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please see the 2nd section of the Custom 404 Error Pages section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add the block `<customErrors>` inside `<system.web>` section ,Like this :

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/error.html" />
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

[Update]
as per the last screenshot this issue should be appeared if :

1. customerror mode is off.
2. statuscode is not matched.

both are not in your web.config , so try iisreset on the server.
Also the web.config attached is similar to the one under "view" folder , try web.config under the web application directly

Comment: But the block is under <system.web> only . Have I to change the name of the file .. you mean ?

Comment: @StrugglingCoder ,In the screen shot customErrors is under <configuration> section directly , it should be like this (I will update the answer) :
<configuration>
   <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On">

Comment: I have put it back under <system.web> but still no luck :( . Please see the updated screenshot .

Comment: @StrugglingCoder ,as per the screenshot you attach , I will update the answer

Comment: I am running on my local. Can IISReset be significant ?

Comment: I tried to simulate your case on my machine with visual studio, and it worked fine, but it gives me the same error only in the mentioned two cases in the answer.
so I guess it's iisreset could help or if you prefer, you could share web.config file to test with it in my machine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105728/discussion-between-ahmed-morsy-and-strugglingcoder).

Comment: I understand. This is really strange. Just one silly question . I do not have an action method named 'aaa' in the 'private' controller. So hitting localhost/private/aaa should ideally throw 404 .. right ? And  so should redirect me to the custom error page .

Comment: I have shared web.config file. Could you please check in your machine ?

Comment: Yes ,writing any action not exist in controller should redirect to custom error page.
I'm sorry i m now away of my machine , I will check it tomorrow and will update you soon

Comment: I checked in my machine , and it also working fine , it's show exception when redirect to the html file but at least it see the file.

Comment: oh .. it's strange. What could possibly cause the difference for me ? :(

Comment: I found something else , the web.config you sent is similar to the one under "view" folder , try web.config under the web application directly.

Comment: Wow man .. that's the reason !! Salutes to you :) You really really helped me. I was almost giving up on this . How stupid was this of me :) Thanks a ton .